# Обход некоторых файлов при сканирование папки

Tags: c#

Есть метод который собирает файл, прошу помочь в некоторых не понятных ситуациях))

```
private static IEnumerable<string> SafeEnumerateFiles(string path, string pattern, SearchOption searchOption)
{
      var dirs = new Stack<string>();
      dirs.Push(path);

      while (dirs.Count > 0)
      {
        string currentDirPath = dirs.Pop();
        if (searchOption == SearchOption.AllDirectories) // В этом условие мы задаём все дириктории.
        {
           try
           {
               string[] subDirs = Directory.GetDirectories(currentDirPath);
               foreach (string subDirPath in subDirs)
               {
                    dirs.Push(subDirPath);
               }
            }
           catch (UnauthorizedAccessException)
           {
               continue;
           }
           catch (DirectoryNotFoundException)
           {
               continue;
           }
        }

        string[] files = null;
        try
                {
                    files = Directory.GetFiles(currentDirPath, pattern);
                }
                catch (UnauthorizedAccessException)
                {
                    continue;
                }
                catch (DirectoryNotFoundException)
                {
                    continue;
                }

                foreach (string filePath in files) 
                {
                    yield return filePath;
                }
            }
        }
```

1 - Как сделать поиск в одной директории с другим условием `if (searchOption == SearchOption....`

2 - Правильно ли я понял обход некоторых файлов если мне нужно сделать то в этом ниже условие его записывать ?

```
// Список файлов для обхода
public static List<string> AllFiles = new List<string> { "help", "cmd", "winlogon" }; // или + .exe ?

foreach (string filePath in files) // мне тут нужно добавить обход чтобы файлы пропускало из списка List<string>
{
     yield return filePath;
}
```

3 - Переменная `string currentDirPath = dirs.Pop();` может возвращать исключения как их обойти если в конце стоит `yield return` ?

4 - В чём разница между `Stack<string>` и `Queue<string>` ? Дают ли они какое-то преимущество?

P.S: Хочу просто понять как что работает, что можно изменять подстраивать под себя и.т.п особо не ругайте ))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1 - Как сделать поиск в одной директории с другим условием if (searchOption == SearchOption....

Вызвать ваш код с другим параметром.

```
private static IEnumerable<string> SafeEnumerateFiles(string path, 
                                   string pattern, 
                                   SearchOption searchOption)
```

> 2 - Правильно ли я понял обход некоторых файлов если мне нужно сделать то в этом ниже условие его записывать ?

Это просто несвязанный набор слов. Думаю, будет здорово вам переформулировать ваш вопрос, чтобы можно было вас понять.

```
public static HashSet<string> AllFiles = new HashSet<string> { "help", "cmd", "winlogon" }; 

foreach (string filePath in files
                             .Where(f => !AllFiles.Contains(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(f))))
{
    yield return filePath;
}
```

без LINQ

```
foreach (string filePath in files)
{
    if (!AllFiles.Contains(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(filePath)))
        yield return filePath;
}
```

> 3 - Переменная string currentDirPath = dirs.Pop(); может возвращать исключения как их обойти если в конце стоит yield return ?

```
if (dirs.Count > 0) { .... dirs.Pop();... }
```

> 4 - В чём разница между Stack и Queue ?

[Алгоритмы и структуры данных для начинающих: стеки и очереди](https://tproger.ru/translations/stacks-and-queues-for-beginners/)

> Дают ли они какое-то преимущество?

Преимущество перед чем? Переформулируйте вопрос.

> P.S: Хочу просто понять как что работает, что можно изменять подстраивать под себя и.т.п особо не ругайте ))

Чтобы понимать как работает ваш код, просто не пишите код, который не понимаете. Если используете что то, то попробуйте сначала сами поискать информацию по вашим структурам данных, прежде чем задавать вопрос, это вам поможет лучше освоить материал. А так вы спросите, вам быстро ответят и вы считай забыли о чем речь была.

**UPD**

Последний блок кода я бы переделал вот так

```
var files = new string[0];
try
{
    files = Directory.GetFiles(currentDirPath, pattern);        
}
catch (UnauthorizedAccessException)
{
    // хотя бы логгирование добавьте
}
catch (DirectoryNotFoundException)
{   
    // хотя бы логгирование добавьте
}

foreach (string filePath in files)
{
    yield return filePath;
}
```

Comment: А как без Linq сделать?

Comment: @Luser что сделать?

Comment: вот этот пример: `.Where(f => !AllFiles.Contains(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(f))))`

Comment: Вы спросили преимущество перед чем, я точно не знаю поэтому интересуюсь даже если и не понимаю многого, даёт ли это что-нибудь в виде прироста сбора файлов, или чему-нибудь другому?!

Comment: @Luser обновил ответ про LINQ, `Stack и Queue` различаются порядком обработки элементов, потому если вам порядок не важен, то разницы для вас нет.

Comment: Спасибо! теперь буду знать.

Comment: Ещё один вопрос возник последний )) Имеет ли смысл заменить `string[] files = null;` на `List<string>` и где получаем файлы добавить их в переменную `List<string>` и после уже пройтись в цикле?

Comment: @Luser обновил ответ

Comment: Попробовал заменить последний блок кода на ваш, студия мне говорит что: `Нельзя использовать оператор yield в теле блока try, имеющего предложение catch`

Comment: @Luser ха, да, совсем забыл про это ограничение (писал код без студии). Поправил ответ, но, по идее, вы можете код тогда ваш оставить как есть, он будет также неплохо работать.